# Facebook page photos RSS

Tags: facebook, rss

I would like to make a page on my site where I merge all the photos from different Facebook page's albums.

Of course, after I have been approved by them (somehow), to grab their photos when they upload on facebook

I'm thinking to do this through RSS feeds?

Can I do this? Does Facebook allow such option? What should I look into?

I'm not sure if its possible, just something I have imagined could work out good.

I would like to be a site, that is a 'collector' of multiple facebook page's albums photos. And I sync with the rss feeds I will grab the uploaded photos (links?) in the rss feed from the facebook page.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. It would be possible to do via the Graph API as long as you are the owner of all the photos.